# Possible to release both a WP7 and WP7.5 app to the marketplace at the same time?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have read this:
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/08/15/what-happens-when-i-publish-a-windows-phone-mango-application-update.aspx
and this:
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/09/20/submit-windows-phone-7-5-apps-today-update-7-0-apps-in-october.aspx

But still not sure.

I am launching a new app at the end of the month, but I want to launch the 7.0 and Mango versions on the same day (1st November for example). How is this possible? I am submitting the WP7.0 version today for testing.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit an application, correct me if I am wrong but you should be able to specify whether it publishes automatically when it passes certification - so in this case, you'd simply submit both and wait until both have passed certification, before publishing them at the same time?

Comment: Thanks thats what I am doing, although the Mango version has been named 1.1 as it has to be an update of the nodo version.